# Air ANE - linking native so libraries

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, javacv, ane

I'm trying to use JavaCV on a AIR project. I built a native extension and it compile well but at runtime i get the following error:

```
W/dalvikvm(16234): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
W/dalvikvm(16234): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
W/dalvikvm(16234): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
W/dalvikvm(16234): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
W/dalvikvm(16234): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
I/dalvikvm(16234): Could not find method java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSampleModel, referenced from method org.bytedeco.javacpp.helper.opencv_core$AbstractIplImage.createFrom
W/dalvikvm(16234): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8824: Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;.getSampleModel ()Ljava/awt/image/SampleModel;
D/dalvikvm(16234): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
W/dalvikvm(16234): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
W/dalvikvm(16234): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
D/dalvikvm(16234): GC_CONCURRENT freed 612K, 7% free 9380K/10028K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 35ms
```

Looks like I'm not linking the library resource properly and the doc on the topics seems really limited.

Any idea or gotcha when linking .jar and armeabi/*_*.so libraries to an ANE?

Updated error log after upgrading to latest javacv source:

```
W/dalvikvm(14799): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/avutil;
W/dalvikvm(14799): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/avformat;
W/dalvikvm(14799): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core;
```

Comment: opened a thread on adobe forum as well: https://forums.adobe.com/message/6631200#6631200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Linking .so dependencies:**

You should make sure that your folder structure is correct. See ["This link"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf268776665d7970d-2e74ffb4130044f3619-7fff.html) under **Android native libraries section**. Simply placing your .so native dependencies inside the "libs/target_platform/" folder makes sure that ADT puts them in the correct place inside the final APK.

Example: **YOUR_ANE_ROOT_FOLDER/android/libs/armeabi-v7a/libYourLibrary.so**

If you support multiple architectures your might also have a 
YOUR_ANE_ROOT_FOLDER/android/libs/**armeabi**/libYourLibrary.so

and so on..

Also make sure that your shared object is named with the "lib" prefix. Example: **libYourLibrary.so**

**Linking JAR dependencies:**

If specifying your JAR dependencies in the platform.xml under the "packagedDependencies" tags doesn't work, you can try to extract all external JARs and include them inside your final jar.

Example:

```
        <javac source="1.6" srcdir="../android/src" destdir="../android/temp/classes" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath>
          <pathelement location="${android.sdk}/android.jar"/>
          <pathelement location="../android/libs/FlashRuntimeExtensions.jar"/>
          <pathelement location="../android/libs/android-support-v4.jar"/>
          <pathelement location="../android/libs/opencv.jar"/>
          ....
          ....
        </classpath>
      </javac>

      <mkdir dir="../android/temp/zip"/>
      <unzip src="../android/libs/opencv.jar" dest="../android/temp/zip"/>
      <unzip src="../android/libs/android-support-v4.jar" dest="../android/temp/zip"/>
      ...
      ...

      <copydir src="../android/temp/zip/com" dest="../android/temp/classes/com"/>
      <copydir src="../android/temp/zip/android" dest="../android/temp/classes/android"/>

      <mkdir dir="../temp/android/"/>
      <copy todir="../temp/android/res/">
        <fileset dir="../android/res"/>
      </copy>
      <jar destfile="../temp/android/lib${name}.jar">
        <fileset dir="../android/temp/classes"/>
      </jar>
      <delete dir="../android/temp"/>
```

If these classes still don't make it to your final APK then see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258049/advertisingidclient-getadvertisingidinfocontext-is-thworing-noclassdeffounderr/25264720?noredirect=1#comment39367875_25264720)!

Comment: So i copied the libs (and libs/armeabi) into my ANE android directory. Got rid of platform.xml and now I get the following error: unable to resolve static method 3499: Lorg/bytedeco/javacv/FrameRecorder;.createDefault (Ljava/io/File;II)Lorg/bytedeco/javacv/FrameRecorder;

Comment: So are your shared objects are being loaded now? Could you please verify if all thirdparty classes are being resolved. You want to look for any "Class not found" errors before the errors that you posted.