# AdvertisingIdClient asking for meta-data although it has been included

Tags: android, xml, google-play-services, ads, air-native-extension

I am trying to create `ANE` to get `AdvertisingId` for android. I am using `Flash Builder 4.7` with `AIR SDK 14.0`. I could successfully create the `ANE`, but the problem is, it is always throwing error as

```
A required `meta-data` tag in your app's `AndroidManifest.xml` does not exist.
You must have the following declaration within the
<application> element:
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I have already added this meta-data in `AndroidManifest.xml` which is in Java application of my `ANE`. If i include this in `Application-app.xml`'s `android->application` tag, it won't throw any error but it won't go forward.

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.androidnativeextensions"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


        <activity
            android:name="com.company.androidnativeextensions.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your metadata usage seems fine. The issue lies with the android build system not being able to  resolve `@integer/google_play_services_version` which comes from `res/values/version.xml`.

This wouldn't have even been an issue on just another android project but since this is an ANE project, it is up to ADT to put the `res` folder in the right place inside the final APK. That's what packagedResources are for.

NOTE: It is not necessary to have any packagedDependencies specified inside Platform.xml in order to use packagedResources. It is perfectly alright to have a Platform.xml that only has packagedResources specified.

Here's the [Link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf268776665d7970d-2e74ffb4130044f3619-7ff8.html) to Adobe's page about including resources in your ANE builds with relevant examples.

Worst case you can replace `@integer/google_play_services_version` with the value inside `version.xml`.