# AIR Google Play Services library classes missing apk

Tags: air, apk, google-play-services, ane

I am working on a test app to test an ane I have built with Google Play Services included. I had things working fine, but recently I updated the version of the Google Play Services library I was using, and now when I built the project in Adobe Flash CC, it seems to be stripping out the Google Play Services classes from the apk. When I decompile the apk I can see they are missing. When I put back the old version of GPlay, I can see it doesn't strip them out.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258049/advertisingidclient-getadvertisingidinfocontext-is-thworing-noclassdeffounderr) post mentions a tool within the AIR needs updating (dx.jar) and [this](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/issue-including-google-play-services-inside-an-android-ane) post seems to have the same message. I did update that file but it did not fix the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be with the AIR SDK. You need to update the `dx.jar` in your AIR SDK, I've logged an issue with Adobe about this but they haven't updated the build tools as yet so we have to do it manually:

Have a look here for the details: http://airnativeextensions.com/knowledgebase/tutorial/5

It's important that you have a recent version of the Android SDK installed and updated for this to work.

Also rather than packaging the Google Play Libraries into your ANE I suggest you use a shared ANE, like this one:
https://github.com/distriqt/ANE-googleplayservices

Otherwise you can cause conflicts with other ANE's that use the Google Play Library.

Comment: I downloaded the latest SDK build tools and grabbed dx.jar out of that and updated my AIR sdk, but I'm still seeing the same result. When I compile an app manually (via mxmlc and adt), I see GPlay is not stripped out, but creating the apk through Flach CC still has the problem.

Comment: That is a good point! I went into Preferences and, under "Compiler" i made sure the Flex SDK Path was set to the AIR sdk I updated. Still saw the same problem though : (

Comment: Is this also the case for AIR SDK 23.0??

Comment: No you haven't needed to update the `dx.jar` since AIR 20 I believe.